# Can you insert ignore into table if certain fields are duplicate?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to insert into a MySQL table, but I came across a problem that I can't seem to solve. The problem is that I want to add a record into the table if certain fields are duplicate, but not all.

To make my problem more clear this is the table:

[image: table]

When I want to do an insert into this table, I want to insert ignore only if userid and status and url are duplicate. If one of those 3 are unique the record can be added into the table.

What I have tried:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO mydb.mytable (unique_screen_id, userid, url, status) 
    VALUES ('1234', 1, 'something.com', 'active');
```

This does not give the desired result since unique_screen_id will never be duplicate and thus the statement will insert the record. I can't remove the unique_screen_id out of the query since it also needs to be added into the table

Which query can I use so that if I insert the record above, it will check if userid **and** status **and** url are duplicate, and if they are ignore the statement (and otherwise insert the statement)?

**Edit:**

As requested my create table query:

```
CREATE TABLE `screens` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `unique_screen_id` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `userid` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` enum('active','finished') DEFAULT 'active',
  `url` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

Comment: Please can you show us create table statement ?

Comment: Please update your question with the full defintion of the current table *(all columns, indexes, constraints, keys, triggers, etc)*.  Then also add examples of what you want to allow and what you want to reject *(such as a sequence of 10 insert statements, showing which should be rejected and why)*.

Comment: Oh, and please stop using strings to represent and/or store integers.

Comment: @MatBailie My integers are not saved as integers (see the create statement), that is how mysql workbench displays it if you have no data in the table. Unique_screen_id is a combination of letters and numbers, that why that is a varchar

Comment: You're still inserting `'1'` *(which is a string)* as the `userid`, when it should just be `1` *(which is an integer)*.  You also haven't shown any constraints, keys, etc, or any example data demonstrating cases that should be accepted or rejected.  Please read this: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what your create table statement is like but you can add UNIQUE key:

```
UNIQUE (userid ,url, status)
```

[Here is a demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ab00ff60e00957bf6fb9cdaeeb7f9ecd)

So first you create table like this(without UNIQUE KEY):

```
CREATE TABLE `screens2` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `unique_screen_id` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `userid` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` enum('active','finished') DEFAULT 'active',
  `url` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

then if you add this line

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO screens2 ( unique_screen_id, userid, url, status) 
    VALUES ( 1, '1', 'something.com', 'active');
```

and then this line

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO screens2 ( unique_screen_id, userid, url, status) 
    VALUES ( 1, '1', 'something.com', 'finished');
```

and then this line

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO screens2 ( unique_screen_id, userid, url, status) 
    VALUES ( 2, '1', 'something.com', 'finished');
```

all 3 lines will be inserted...

If you create your table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `screens` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `unique_screen_id` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `userid` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` enum('active','finished') DEFAULT 'active',
  `url` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  unique(userid, url, status)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

Only two of the lines will be inserted and one will be ignored.
P.S. If you add UNIQUE key you will no IGNORE keyword with your insert statements.

Comment: If you're not sure what is needed, then this should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I do understand what is needed I do not have create tale statement "I am not sure what your create table statement is like"

Comment: Hmmm, what is wrong with my suggestion on adding unique key ?

Comment: @VBoka id and unique_screen_id and userid need to be 3 different fields

Comment: Hi @coder, they are in my demos....

Comment: Hi @Coder so you can not use my answer because ... ?

Comment: Sorry, I made myself more clear in the previous comment @VBoka

Comment: Hi @Coder but they are not part of your question. You only mention unique_screen_id, userid, url, status ? So I do not understand what you want to point out with this statement : " id and unique_screen_id and userid need to be 3 different fields" ?

Comment: @VBoka In the demo you gave you have the following fields:
unique_screen_id, id, status, url. I need to have the following fields: id, unique_screen_id, userid, status, url.

Comment: Hi @Coder, change your question from "INSERT IGNORE INTO mydb.mytable (unique_screen_id, userid, url, status)" to real insert statement because it has to include userid. And change the text in your question because my answer is applyable to any number of columns but apparently you do not understand the answer.

Comment: Hi @Coder I have updated my answer... This now explains in details what you need to do and with the columns you have....

Answer (score 0):

As the user VBoka suggested the following demo displays the answer!

I needed to use a combination of the insert ignore statement and the Unique keyword!

Thanks!

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=5d19c458568ef9204c257b7ef6096eab